# How do I identify the correct driver to blacklist in modprobe?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, kernel

Without disabling anything in my bios, I want to disable and keep the OS from loading any drivers or registering the smartcard contact interface that is part of my laptop.

I understand that this can be accomplished by adding the driver for the smartcard to the blacklist file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` in the following manner:

```
blacklist driver-name
```

How can I detect the "driver-name" for the BROADCOM device below?

```
$ opensc-tool -l -r 0
# Detected readers (pcsc)
Nr.  Card  Features  Name
0    Yes             Yubico Yubikey NEO OTP+CCID 00 00
1    No              Broadcom Corp 5880 [Contacted SmartCard]      
(0123456789ABCD) 01 00
```

Comment: it should be ccid driver (such as `libccid`). What do you see in `lsmod`?

Comment: I have nothing in the output of lsmod that includes the text 'ccid'

Comment: @Ron you were close, `libccid` is a user space driver, which communicate through `libusb` directly with the device, and no kernel module is loaded , only parent node have same usb driver which we can't block it (otherwise it disables the complete usb bus). Many developers prefer user space driver because they are easy to develop and to maintain it .

Answer (score 0):

- No use, you can't block it that way, because it does not have a kernel space driver (module). As you can see it is `UNCLAIMED`. I've same device in Dell Latitude E6410.

  **`lsusb -d 0a5c:5800`**

  ```
  Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0a5c:5800 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor
  ```

  **`sudo lsusb -t`** (See Bus 2 Device 5, took from above output)

  ```
  /:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/3p, 480M
      |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
          |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
          |__ Port 8: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 12M
          |__ Port 8: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Chip/SmartCard, Driver=, 12M
  /:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/3p, 480M
      |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
  ```

  **`sudo lshw`**

  ```
               *-usb:1 UNCLAIMED
                    description: Generic USB device
                    product: 5880
                    vendor: Broadcom Corp
                    physical id: 8
                    bus info: usb@2:1.8
                    version: 1.01
                    serial: 0123456789ABCD
                    capabilities: usb-1.10
                    configuration: maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
  ```
- It is using a *user space driver* like `libccid` that communicate through `libusb` , the only way to stop it, is to stop any tool that use it like `pcscd`, `pam` could have a module for it too.

Answer (score -2):

You could try this, and enter this in the terminal:

```
 modprobe -c lspci | lspci usb
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: This returns invalid option -- 'l'

Comment: As a famous philosopher once
said “Do, or do not! There is no try!” or in Ask Ubuntu style: if you're
sure, then it's an answer, if you're not, then it's a comment. Words
like "try" "might", "should" are a sign, that a message belongs in the
comments, and "do", "will", "shall" in answers.

Comment: And now `lspci: invalid option -- 'c'`